# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 IntelliSense (already refreshed cache)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm running *SQL Management Studio 11.0.5058.0* about an year.

*IntelliSense* works as expected for current databases with **SQL Server 2008 R2** I only need to refresh cache sometimes.

Now we are testing two new **SQL Server 2014** instances and in none of them I managed to make *IntelliSense* shows.

If I connect to the older instance right now it still works. A college of mine is using the same version of *Management Studio* and it works with the new instance.

Things I've already tried:

- Refresh local cache <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with a query in focus
- Refresh local cache with mouse
- Refresh local cache and restart SSMS
- Reboot the PC
- Repair the installation of their Management Objects
- Reset the settings
- Restore settings from a PC where it is working

P.S.
I want to fix this functionality and not replace with another tool.

Comment: Install `SSMS 2014`, new version should be backward compatible with older ones, but not vice versa

Comment: @lad2025 Well, I think it can be considered as "replace with another tool". But as a last resort I'll end up doing this or an uninstall/reinstall. ;)

Comment: You want older version to work with newer, It won't always work that way, but if you find solution let me know.

Comment: @lad2025. Sure. But I read that this particular feature should work whatever version beyond 2008.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps (I did not try it), but check if there is an update to update SSMS. Also check if there is an update for SQL Server. There is also a configuration about `intellisense` in which you can increase cache (check the interenet about that)

Comment: Thanks @bogdan-bogdanov, I've already tried to increase the cache after those attempts. I checked Windows Update and no updates were available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on try to fix this in a simple way.

So I went to "*Programs and Features*" and uninstalled everything with "*Microsoft SQL Server 2012*" in its name.

I discovered that maybe uninstalling just "*Microsoft SQL Server 2012*" or "*Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (x64)*" should work.

**It fixed my problem.**

Before that I tried to delete files in **AppData** folder but SSMS recreated it and it was still with the problem.